# Error after upgraded to Meteor 0.9.1

Tags: meteor, meteorite, iron-router

After upgraded Meteor from 0.9.0.1 to 0.9.1, I got the following errors in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'registerHelper' of undefined 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'T9n' of undefined 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'AccountsEntry' of undefined 
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: Meteor is not define
Exception in defer callback: ReferenceError: Spacebars is not defined
```

It seems that the changes are not backwards compatible.

Comment: They are supposed to... what packages are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a package that is not compatible. To check what this is look at your server console.

If you want to brute force your way into getting it to work, `git clone` the offending package into `/packages` and it should get it to work (also add it with `meteor add xx` where `xx` is the name of the directory in `/packages`

Additionally rename the following (even though you would not yet have to) to bring it up to date:

```
UI.registerHelper -> Template.registerHelper
Handlebars.registerHelper -> Template.registerHelper
```

Comment: following last line of renaming i get "Template" is undefined.

Comment: @Amc_rtty you're likely using a package. Don't forget to including `templating` as one of your package imports with `api.use`